# How do I find the path to the home directory for Linux?

Tags: rust

I need the path contained in `$HOME`, the path to the home directory. The function [`home_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/env/fn.home_dir.html) seems to do exactly that but is deprecated. What should I use in its place?

The documentation says this :

> Deprecated since 1.29.0:
> This function's behavior is unexpected and probably not what you want. Consider using a crate from crates.io instead.

What type of crate should I use instead? Is there really no alternative in standard Rust?

Comment: Pick any one from the search that works for you — https://crates.io/search?page=1&per_page=10&q=home

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the [`home`](https://crates.io/crates/home) crate.

> The definition of `home_dir` provided by the standard library is incorrect because it relies on the `$HOME` environment variable which has basically no meaning in Windows. This causes surprising situations where a Rust program will behave differently depending on whether it is run under a Unix emulation environment. Neither Cargo nor rustup use the standard libraries definition - instead they use the definition here.

There is [discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71684) about bringing `home_dir` back into the standard library, but for now the [`home`](https://crates.io/crates/home) crate is probably your best option. It provides canonical definitions of `home_dir`, `cargo_home`, and `rustup_home`:

```rust
match home::home_dir() {
    Some(path) => println!("{}", path.display()),
    None => println!("Impossible to get your home dir!"),
}
```

Answer (score 10):

From the [dirs](https://crates.io/crates/dirs) crate.

Note that the crate provides paths to many standard directories as defined by operating systems rules, not only the home directory:

Experience has shown that 90% of those asks for `$HOME` are better served by one of the other functions this crate provides.

If your requirements are more complex, e. g. computing cache, config, etc. paths for specific applications or projects, consider using the [directories](https://crates.io/crates/directories) crate instead.

Answer (score 2):

From the [simple-home-dir](https://crates.io/crates/simple-home-dir) crate.

```rust
use simple_home_dir::*;

fn main() {
    let home = home_dir().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", home)
}
```